# Can I use vue packages in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Now I am working on a Nuxt project. Currently, there are many useful packages that make vue more enjoyable to use. But I've managed to find Nuxt packages. So I am wondering if there is any good way to use Vue packages in Nuxt projects. For example, vue has good packages related to google map including `vue-google-maps`. It would be great if I can use it in Nuxt.

Comment: The nuxt website covers this actually quite well: ```The plugins directory contains your Javascript plugins that you want to run before instantiating the root Vue.js Application. This is the place to add Vue plugins and to inject functions or constants. Every time you need to use Vue.use(), you should create a file in plugins/ and add its path to plugins in nuxt.config.js.``` https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ThomasKuhlmann. That's correct.
One more question, have you ever integrated `google` in nuxtjs?

Comment: No, I am afraid I haven't

Answer (score 1):

`vue-google-maps` [documentation](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps#readme) has an example of how to add the package as a nuxt plugin. Add a js file (eg, `google-maps.js`) in your `/plugins` directory:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  // your config here
}
```

And then, in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/google-maps' },
  ],
```

Most Vue packages should work just fine in Nuxt after these steps.